# Show toast WHILE dialog is open?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, in-app-purchase

This is an extremely simple issue I am facing. Basically, I am requesting run-time permissions—but I also want to show a toast at the same time as the permission request:

**Relevent Code:**

```
if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{


                                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 4);

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must enable BOTH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The problem is, the toast quickly disappears (within maybe less than 0.5 second), as soon as the permission dialog appears.

[image]

Is this a bug on Android? Or is there some work around that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Toasts don't display permanently.  The entire concept of a Toast is that it pops up then fades away.  If you want something more permanent, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I know that, I've been using toasts for as long as I can remember :) the problem here is that the system's own dialog is interfering with my toast, by forcing it to abruptly disappearing as soon as the permission dialog appears.

Answer (score 0):

It's default dialog for permission in android so no solution for this.ya but if you make your custom dialog then you can show it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Toast message is displayed for short duration of 2 sec or for long duration of 3.5 sec and it cannot be changed.

If you wish to display the toast message for longer time then you need to display it continuously.

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Your toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It will display your toast for 10 seconds.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the context as

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"YOUR TEXT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```